# Is there a way to apply the styling of only the child element to a different unrelated element

Tags: html, css

1. I want to apply the styling of the '.first' class only on the third `<p>` content.
2. I want to apply the styling of both the '.social' and '.first' on the third `<p>` content.

How to carry out the above 2 operations. Any suggestions?

```css
.social {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}

.second {
  color: blue;
}

.social .first {
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p class="social">taco
  <span class="first">chimichangaff</span></p>
<p class="second">burrito</p>
<p class="first">chimichangaff</p>
```

Comment: define the `first` CSS class separately, do not use `first` for `<span>` in the first `<p>` element, and add both `social` and `first` as classes to the third `<p>` element

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
p.first {
    font-weight:bold;
}
span.first{
    color:black;
}
.second {
    color: blue;
}
.social, p.first {
    color: green;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="check.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="social">taco
            <span class="first">chimichangaff</span></p>
        <p class="second">burrito</p>
        <p class="first">chimichangaff</p>
    </body>
</html>
```